# Toggle scss variable file

Tags: css, variables, import, sass, styling

I am trying to make a toggle between night mode and day mode only by changing colors. I have some base color variables inside my `_colors.scss`, and they are used all over my site. I use React to toggle a className between 'night-mode' and 'day-mode' at the first div of the project. 
I have tried to wrap the variables in the mentioned class names, but the result is that no other files can access the variables. Therefore I was hoping for a solution where I can use a night-mode file and a day-time file and toggle between them.

As I see it now, the issue is that I can't wrap the $variables *or* the @import in a class name, which makes it difficult to know what mode is selected. I am looking for a solution that does not include jQuery (I have a variable globally stored that can be used for javascript reference if that ends up to be the best solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't toggle scss files at runtime, since they are already compiled to css.

I would go with CSS custom properties (sometimes called CSS variables) instead of pure Sass variables.

Example:

```
:root {
  --background: lightblue;
}


.night-mode {
  --background: darkblue;
}

.component {
  background-color: var(--background);
}
```

Toggle the class .night-mode on  with javascript depending on the time of day.

You may of course feed your CSS custom properties from Sass variables in your scss files:

```
$bg-day: lightblue;
$bg-night: darkblue;

:root {
  --background: $bg-day;
}

.night-mode {
  -- background: $bg-night;
}

.component {
  background-color: var(--background);
}
```

Comment: I haven't had the time to implement it yet, but I have done some researching on CSS variables as this was not a concept I was familiar with. Seems to be the right answer, and I also wanted to add this link just in case someone stumbles over this q: https://medium.com/geckoboard-under-the-hood/how-we-made-our-product-more-personalized-with-css-variables-and-react-b29298fde608